# Log transformed histogram distribution

Tags: bugs, probability-or-statistics, distributions, logarithmic-scale

**Bug introduced in 11.0.1 or earlier and persisting through 11.3.0 or later**

I try to get a `Log` transformed histogram data I get from a different program

```
examplefile = 
     {{0., 70.110492289066920}, {20., 6.80630499020644475}, {40.,
       8.42161}, {60., 15.06519919414850448}, {80., 
      8.2318220556770346}, {100., 87.478685125810497}, {120., 
      4161.7690039964691}, {140., 84754.765836040083}, {160., 
      532571.989049240777}, {180., 857574.30987846023}, {200., 
      299164.78794849526}, {220., 21296.4007456827975}, {240., 
      324.610011732739988}}
```

I convert this to a distribution by:

```
 \[ScriptCapitalD]exmp = HistogramDistribution[
   WeightedData[examplefile[[;; , 1]], examplefile[[;; , 2]]], {20}];
```

And do a `Log` transform:

```
\[ScriptCapitalD]log = TransformedDistribution[Log[x], 
     x \[Distributed] \[ScriptCapitalD]exmp]
```

Now `RandomVariate` is working fine:

```
Histogram[RandomVariate[\[ScriptCapitalD]log, 10000]]
```

[image]

But `PDF` is showing nothing:

```
Plot[PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD]log, y], {y, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Do I do something wrong, or can I just not use `PDF`?

Comment: try `Plot[Evaluate@PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD]log, y], {y, 0, 10}]`?

Comment: @kglr, thanks. I get the same resulting plot

Comment: this must be version/os related. `Plot[Evaluate@PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD]log, y], {y, 0, 10}]` works in version 9 (windows 10) but not in version 11 (wolfram cloud).

Comment: The PDF looks really weird in Mathematica 11.3. Look here http://i.stack.imgur.com/2G8QM.png

Comment: Please add the standard bug header instead of changing the title https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1611/12

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In version 9,

```
Plot[Evaluate@PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD]log, y], {y, 0, 10}] (* and *)
Plot[PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD]log, y], {y, 0, 10}, Evaluated -> True]
```

give

[image]

In version 11.3, there seems to be a bug in computation of the `PDF`

```
PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD]log, y]
```

[image]

The issue is that  `Boole[{...} <= E^y <{...}]` doesn't thread.

The fix is easy: simply modify the piecewise expression by explicitly `Thread`ing the argument  of `Boole`:

```
pdf = Function[y, PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD]log, y] /. Boole[a_] :> Boole[Thread[a]]];

Plot[Evaluate@pdf[ y], {y, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: `Plot[pdf[y], {y, Log[#[[1]]], Log[#[[2]]]}, PlotRange -> All, 
    ImageSize -> Medium] & /@ {{1, 120}, {120, 260}} // Column` shows additional data

Comment: Do we agree that a bug tag is applicable?

Comment: @Ruud3.1415, I think so. I suggest you report this to Wolfram.